# Is there a way to Batch Insert Records in google Firebase database under Windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, firebase

the below code for inserting one record to google firebase using [Firesharp](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp)

libarary for c# under windows forms ,but i want to insert bulk records at ones , like in sql SQL server

```
bulk.DestinationTableName = "test";
    bulk.WriteToServer(table);
```

code for inserting one record to firebase

```
class Student
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string RollNo { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
}
IFirebaseConfig ifc = new FirebaseConfig()
    {
        AuthSecret= "_AuthSecret",
        BasePath= "_BasePath"
    };

 IFirebaseClient client;
Student std = new Student()
            {
                FullName=nameTbox.Text,
                RollNo=rollTbox.Text,
                Grade=gradeTbox.Text,
                Section=secTbox.Text
            };
            var set = client.Set(@"Students/"+ rollTbox.Text,std);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you 
I Solved My Problem by Using REST API  using Post Method ,but firstly created an JASON for all my records to post it at once as Follows

```
// Instanciating with base URL
            FirebaseDB firebaseDB = new FirebaseDB("Firebase Base link");

            // Referring to Node with name "Teams"
            FirebaseDB firebaseDBTeams = firebaseDB.Node("Teams");
            var data = @"{
                            'Team-Awesome': {
                                'Members': {
                                    'M1': {
                                        'City': 'Giza',
                                        'Name': 'Isaac'
                                        },
                                    'M2': {
                                        'City': 'Cairo',
                                        'Name': 'Be'
                                        },
                                    'M3': {
                                        'City': 'France',
                                        'Name': 'Pradeep'
                                        }
                                   }
                               }
                          }";



            WriteLine("POST Request");
            FirebaseResponse postResponse = firebaseDBTeams.Post(data);
            WriteLine(postResponse.Success);
            WriteLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Database API does not have a specific operation for batch writes. If you want to write more data in one go, you'll just have to pass more data into one of the existing methods.

A few things to keep in mind there:

1. Calling `Set` on a location replaces all existing data at that location with the new data you pass in.
2. Calling `Push` writes the data you pass in on a new child location with a unique name under the location.
3. Calling `Update` updates the existing data in the location with the new data that you pass in.

For individual additional to a list, you'll typically use `Push` so that Firebase generates a unique name for the new data (starting with `-L...` at the moment).

For writing/updating multiple children you'll normally use `Update`, since that allows you to write the new data without disturbing the existing data. Firebase won't generate the keys for you in that case, so you'll have to ensure the unique keys for the data are present in the call to `Update` already.

The latter might look something like this:

```
var students = new Dictionary<string, Student>
{
    { Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), new Student() { ... } },
    { Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), new Student() { ... } },
    { Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), new Student() { ... } }
};

await  _client.UpdateAsync("Students", students);
```